# Android https intent handler and browser redirects

Tags: android, browser, redirect, android-intent

I configured my application to handle intents to view

- https://mydomain

and it's working well when triggered normally. However, when the link is posted on Facebook, FB "wraps" it in the form of

- http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain

which causes my app not to be suggested in the intent popup window, but only regular browsers.

I tried to circumvent this by making an intermediary page on my domain that will redirect to the actual page. The intermediary page would get "wrapped" by facebook, but the actual page should trigger my app.

I tried both HTTP 302 redirect, and javascript `location.replace()` redirect. However the browser just opens the page, without asking the user with what app he wishes to open it.

However in other cases (most notably google sign-ins) redirects cause the intent handler dialog to pop up multiple times.

So my question is, what am I doing incorrectly ?